# How to hide Server parameter in response header with Traefik in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

I need to hide technologies I'm working with in a project and Im using Traefik on a kubernetes cluster I created a middleware like this:

```
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: test-header
spec:
  headers:
    customResponseHeaders:
      x-powered-by: ""
```

but nothing is happening the technogies is still available on the browser do you have any idea please

Comment: Have you added the middleware to the actual IngressRoute? You need to not only create the middleware, but tell traefik to use that middleware for the route. You can see how to do this in their [example IngressRoute](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-ingressroute)

Comment: Yeah I aleardy did add the Middleware to the ingressrout but nothing is happening